# Flavoured source code is not compiled in Android

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-flavors

I have two flavours in my app with the following structure:

```
src
   |
    flavour_1
   |         |
   |          java
   |         |
   |          res
   |
    flavour_2
             |
              java
             |
              res
```

and here is my app gradle:

```
productFlavors{
        flavour_1{
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".flavour_1"
            versionNameSuffix "-flavour_1"
        }

        flavour_2{
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".flavour_2"
            versionNameSuffix "-flavour_2"
        }

    }

    sourceSets {
        flavour_2{
            java{
                srcDirs = ["src/flavour_2/java", "src/main/java"]
            }
        }
    }
```

Using different resources works perfectly fine but, when I have a new source code, then it gets messy. If I debug it, it starts with the code in main app and then goes to the flavoured one but surprisingly it does not do what it is on the flavoured one... it still follows the main source.

I have tried to clean and rebuild. Also removed the caches. I introduced sourceSets in my app gradle pointing to the folder where the flavours keep the code. But none works!

What am I missing in my structure or configuring my flavours?

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve here, but maybe the error is the extra space in the applicationIdSuffix?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo

Comment: I don't know if it's the problem, but I don't think you need that `sourceSets` block.  It should look for sources there by default anyway.  Can you describe the behavior in a little more detail?  I'm not sure I'm following what is happening.  Also if you see something when debugging that doesn't seem right it may be worth using some logging statements to double check what the debugger shows.

Comment: after checking different solutions and my app's log, I realised that the problem is that I have two activities in my app and I am trying to override a piece of code in my secondary activity... I believe it is the reason, but I don't know how one should override a code in a nested activity!